# Calculator doesnt work

Tags: android, kotlin, calculator

I have a problems with my calculator

I did it with Kotlin in AndroidStudio and after I finished it didn't work although layout is very good

The Code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)

    val result=findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
    val button_plus=findViewById(R.id.button_plus) as Button
    val button_di=findViewById(R.id.button_di) as Button
    val button_mult=findViewById(R.id.button_mult) as Button
    val button_div=findViewById(R.id.button_div) as Button


    fun getNumber_1():Int{
        val input_num1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext2) as EditText
        return Integer.parseInt(input_num1.text.toString())
    }
    fun getNumber_2():Int{
        val input_num2 = findViewById(R.id.edittext2) as EditText
        return Integer.parseInt(input_num2.text.toString())
    }

    button_plus.setOnClickListener{View.OnClickListener {
        View -> result.text =(getNumber_1() + getNumber_2()).toString()
    }}

    button_di.setOnClickListener { View.OnClickListener {
        View -> result.text =(getNumber_1() - getNumber_2()).toString()
    }}

    button_mult.setOnClickListener { View.OnClickListener {
        View -> result.text =(getNumber_1() * getNumber_2()).toString()
    }}

    button_div.setOnClickListener { View.OnClickListener {
        View -> result.text =(getNumber_1() / getNumber_2()).toString()
    }}
}
```

and thanks

Comment: what not Works?

Comment: what's the problem? why do you mention the layout, but not add the layout code (if that's the problem)?

Comment: The other thing that "didn't work" is your problem description.

Comment: ya, text of the question may be enhanced.

Comment: Please rephrase the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
button_plus.setOnClickListener{View.OnClickListener {
    View -> result.text =(getNumber_1() + getNumber_2()).toString()
}}
```

You should do this:

```
button_plus.setOnClickListener { view ->
    result.text = (getNumber_1() + getNumber_2()).toString()
}
```

The curly braces you open after `setOnClickListener` are the lambda that gets executed when your button is clicked. So what you were doing so far is creating a new `View.OnClickListener` instance every time one of the buttons was clicked, instead of performing the actions you wanted.

In Java code, the equivalent of that would be something like this:

```
button_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    void onClick(View view) {

        new View.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            void onClick(View view) {
                result.setText(...);
            }
        };

    }
});
```

Comment: I cleared the buttons and replaced them with a new codes which you typed  and they doesn't work for bad but when I press the buttons the application close immediately